# Select certain labels in R

Tags: r, select

I've DF with data of one country:

- period (1950-1955, 2005-2010)
- age (0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, ... 75-79, 80+)
- and other columns

And I need to calculate index for both periods (Index1 and Index2) and select only those who is 15-49 years old.
Which formula can help me?

I tried using "[]":

```
kenya[kenya$age == "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49",]
Ошибка в `[.data.frame`(kenya, kenya$age == "15-19", "20-24", "25-29",  :
  неиспользованные аргументы (alist("30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", ))
```

So, I want to select the certain labels of the variable "age" and one period, calculate index using these conditions without saving another DF (if it's possible).

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem with "age", but the problem with the second variable exists.
If I add it using period == "1950-1955", R didn't add it

kenya[kenya$age %in% v1, kenya$period == v2] 
Ошибка в `[.data.frame`(kenya, kenya$age %in% v1, kenya$period == v2) :
  объект 'v2' не найден

Comment: What is the 'period' you want to subset

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If we want to select more than one element, use `%in%`

```
v1 <- c("15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49")
kenya[kenya$age %in% v1,]
```

If we also need to create a logical condition with 'period'

```
kenya[kenya$age %in% v1 & kenya$period == '1950-1955',]
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem with "age", but the problem with the second variable exists.

Comment: @Serena From the question, the second condition is not clear to me.  Can you please update your post with a small reproduciible example and expected ouptut.  what is `Index1` and `Index2`?

Comment: Index1 or Index2 here is not important, it's calculated variables using formula.

When I used this code:

kenya[kenya$age %in% v1 & kenya$period == 1950-1955,]

and then use the function "summary" of my DF I again see both periods, not only "1950-1955", but also "2005-2010". And the same thing with "age".

So, the DF whatever includes them during next calculation.

Comment: @Serena You can use `newdf <- droplevels(kenya[kenya$age %in% v1 & kenya$period == '1950-1955',])